# Many DNS records after creating a subdomain in cPanel

Tags: dns, cpanel

I am new to cPanel but I think I understand the basics of DNS and DNS zones enough.

When I add a new subdomain in cPanel, like sub.example.com, via the subdomain screen, the following records appear automatically in the DNS Zone Editor:

```
www.sub.example.com
webmail.sub.example.com
cpanel.sub.example.com
cpcontacts.sub.example.com
```

I don't need all these records the only one I want is the `A` records of `sub.example.com` and deleting them one by one is a nightmare. There's like maybe 30 records and I want to add several subdomains.

Is there a way to prevent these additional entries from being created or at least to delete multiple entries at the same time?

Comment: I don't think they hurt anything to have them.   Even if they exist, they may never get used.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller seems a lot cleaner to me though to remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CPanel you have so called Zone Templates that define how newly created (sub)domains should look (in terms of added subdomains, TXT or MX entries etc.)

You can change the zone template following this documentation:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Edit+Zone+Templates

Comment: Thanks a lot. That looks exactly like what I would need but seems to be more of a "backend" WHM screen. I should have mentioned that I am on a shared host and I think they do not have that enabled for us users. Probably no luck for me as a user is it? No cpanel config files i could probably edit?

Comment: @frezq as you are only on a shared hosting I don't think you have access to the bind config files which you'd have to edit in order to change the zones.

Also as a user of a shared hosting account you don't have access to those zone templates as there are only global ones, not user specific iirc)

Maybe you can ask your provider if they can bulk-delete them for you :)